# HttpTwo client on server 2008 (APNS with JWT)

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, http2

**EDIT - Due to probable misintepretation:**
This is not about the server side of HTTP/2 - its about a client HTTP/2 request from an older server OS. Also, i got it to work using python (gobiko.apns) , so it seems to me it should be possible.

---

**EDIT 2**
It seems this question has not so much to do with HTTP2, but rather the cipher required by apple. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 is not used by the SslStream in versions pre-win10. However, since it can be done using python, it seems to me that it should be possible. Any help would be appreciated.

---

We found some code here and there to get our connection to the APNS working on our development environment. We are using the .p8 certificate and sign a token as authorization (not the 'old' interface).

This works on my dev pc (win10) but when i transfer it to a server 2008 R2 it gives a weird warning. It seems having to do with the setup of the tls connection, however, i'm not too familiar with that area. I really searched but the only thing i can come up with is that server 2008R2 will not support it due to ciphers or something (which seems unreasonable to me).

The code that is working from my pc (using nuget HttpTwo and Newtonsoft):

```
    public static async void Send2(string jwt, string deviceToken)
    {
        var uri = new Uri($"https://{host}:443/3/device/{deviceToken}");

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ServerCertificateValidationCallback");
            return true;
        };

        string payloadData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            aps = new
            {
                alert = new
                {
                    title = "hi",
                    body = "works"
                }
            }
        });

        //PayloadData always in UTF8 encoding
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payloadData);

        var httpClient = new Http2Client(uri);
        var headers = new NameValueCollection();

        headers.Add("authorization", string.Format("bearer {0}", jwt));
        headers.Add("apns-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        headers.Add("apns-expiration", "0");
        headers.Add("apns-priority", "10");
        headers.Add("apns-topic", bundleId);

        try
        {
            var responseMessage = await httpClient.Send(uri, HttpMethod.Post, headers, data);
            if (responseMessage.Status == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Send Success");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("failure {0}", responseMessage.Status);

                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ex");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return;
        }
    }
```

is throwing

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted
```

from server 2008R2.

I also tried it with a `WinHttpHandler`, which also works from my PC, but throws

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error occurred
```

Stacktraces are mostly async thingies, but it boils down to `HttpTwo.Http2Connection.<Connect>` for the HttpTwo implementation and `System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>` for the WinHttpHandler.

Is there something i have to add to the server in order to work / will we get it to work?

---

**UPDATE**
I included the sourcefiles from HttpTwo in my project and debugged it. The exception occurs on

```
      await sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync (
                ConnectionSettings.Host, 
                ConnectionSettings.Certificates ?? new X509CertificateCollection (), 
                System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12, 
                false).ConfigureAwait (false);
```

on my Win8 test pc. Now, when i use the method overload with only the host argument on my own PC it throws the same exception, i guess because the tls protocol is off then.

According to this [Github issue](https://github.com/Redth/HttpTwo/issues/5) it could have to do with the ciphers. I had some problems before in that area, but it seems to me that at least a WIN8 PC must be able to agree upon secure enough ciphers, right?

Schannel is complaining about "A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 40.", so that points into that direction also afaik.

Comment: As far as i can tell, that question is about the server side of HTTP/2 - my question is about a client implementation running on an older OS. Apart from that, HTTP/2 is still a tcp implementation, right? I figured HttpTwo should be able to run a client request? But, thnx, so it means that Apple forces you to use 'new' window OS?

Comment: I respectfully disagree - it might be off-topic hindsight. I was really hoping that it would be something other like setting some property on the servicepointmanager or something. I had similar problems before and i know for certain that SuperUser of ServerVault would react the same way about those...

Comment: I'm sorry i could not make myself clear to you. I was hoping, some fellow C# developer who had successfully connected to APNS encountered (and fixed) this issue before. My question was really about: Is there anything i can change / add to make my code work.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I don't want to be annoying - i really need to find the answer: you state that it will never work from a old server2008R2. But, i got it to work using Python. (gobiko.apns) How is that possible then?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that Python would be at all comparable to how .NET is implemented.

Comment: I don't. But wouldnt you interpret that as an indication that the OS itself is capable of making a HTTP/2 request? Thus - "You are asking whether HTTP2 can be used on a specific Windows Server version." is not my question anymore. (it wasnt at all). In other words: I hope you will remove the duplication vote, as i'm really still hoping for a solution.

Comment: I have deleted my comments since they don't apply anymore (you can delete yours). Why don't you submit an issue at the HttpTwo GitHub page? Maybe they already know the issue

Comment: Thnx. I guess thats indeed a road to try.

Comment: Another suggestion: download the source code for the library, add that reference (instead of the NuGet package) and debug the source code, maybe you can find the bug there. One last thing: looking here: https://github.com/Redth/HttpTwo/blob/master/HttpTwo/Http2Connection.cs#L50 the library is **pretty bad** so you could look for another if there's any

Comment: Ill sleep over it... Spend the day already.. Haven't been able to find another library. I dunno if its possible (or helps anything) to incorporate .Net Core dll or something. It feels to me that someone should have done this before, its not like ill be the only one with older servers and wanting to send push notifications using .Net.... Anyway, thnx for the sugggestions.

Comment: I have the same issue on 2012 R2, but on Win10 works. The only way then is to send notifications from windows 10/server 2016?

Comment: @MattiaLancieri, the problem is the cipher that Apple uses is not incuded in sChannel below win10/2016. Thus, from a .Net way, the only possibility is indeed win10/server2016 or roll your own encryption suite.

Comment: If the problem in .net implementation then don't use .net implementation. openssl or bouncycastle for tls connection instead sslstream. And now I'm debugging HttpTwo library. Generally it works but with issues.

Answer (score 2):

It's the cipher... The ciphers Apple uses are not included into SChannel below Win10/Server2016.
(see Edit 2)